# In laravel how can i get data in one query from 3 tables

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 tables

```
first table : language
2nd table : user_language 
3rd table : user
```

in user_language table i have stored language_id of  all users  it can be multiple.

```
user_language Table 

user  language_id 
9         5  
13       10
17        8
17        3

language_table 
id     language
5      english
10     hindi
8      Tamil
3      Gujrati

user table 
id   name
9    amit
3    john
17    aman
```

My question is in laravel how can i get all user language in one query. query should be in laravel.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, all you should do is to write something like the following::

User model snippet:

```
public function languages() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Language::class);
}
```

Language model snippet

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

you need to import class at the top

and you can fetch user languages like

for specific user 
`User::with('languages')->where('id', $userId)->first();`

and for all users

`User::with('languages')->get();`

Answer (score 0):

Use many to many relation.

In user model:

```
public function languages()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Language_Model', 'user_language', 'user', 'language_id');
    }
```

The you can access the language using:

```
$user->languages
```

Do give a look at laravel [many-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) documentation, as it has clear information about many to many relationship.

Additionally you can look here for [basic](http://sauravkc.com.np/blog/manytomany-post-tags) usages of many to many relationship.

Comment: What is Language_Model here...  ?

Comment: Your model name for Language table

Answer (score 0):

Use Pivot Relationship.

Pivot relationship is very useful for two table connection using foreign keys.

Refer below link.

[Pivot Relationship](https://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/)